# De-allocate a 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, free

I'm working in C++ and I have to allocate a 3d array of doubles. This is the code used for the allocation:

```
cellMatrix = (double***)malloc(N*sizeof(double**));
if (cellMatrix == NULL)
{
    errorlog("Allocation Error -> CellMatric can't be created");
}
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    cellMatrix[k] = (double**)malloc(M*sizeof(double*));

    if (cellMatrix[k] == NULL)
    {
        errorlog("Allocation Error -> *CellMatric can't be created");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        cellMatrix[k][i] = (double*)malloc(B*sizeof(double));
        if (cellMatrix[k][i] == NULL)
        {
            errorlog("Allocation Error -> **CellMatric can't be created");
        }
    }
}
```

The allocation doesn't have any problem. Finally, when I have to de-allocate the "cube" some issues occurred. This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        free(cellMatrix[i][j]);
    }
    free(cellMatrix[i]);
}
free(cellMatrix);
```

The program stops during the deallocation of cellMatrix[i], printing this error message (Visual Studio Pro '13)

> HOG.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: If you are working in C++ why are you using `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: Run in the debugger to locate the exact location of the crash. And make sure you don't write to any of the arrays out of bounds.

Comment: The code seems correct to me. Maybe you have a stack corruption somewhere else in your code. Valgrind may be very useful in such situations

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev If he is working on Visual Studio, he is working on Windows, so without Valigrind, unfortunately...

Comment: [Visual leak detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) then...

Comment: If one of your intermediate allocations fail, you leak memory. (I'd be very surprised if `errorlog` cleans up memory for you)

Comment: That's not a 3D array, it's a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays of pointers to 1D arrays.  It'd be simpler, and probably more efficient at runtime (better cache locality and less indirection), to allocate a single contiguous array of size `N*M*B`.

Comment: What are N,M and B values? Note that you try to allocate NxMxB doubles, which is NxMxBx8 bytes.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad coding skills, but this is my first important project in C++. I know I'm too C-oriented but it's because I'm not able to manipulate C++ syntax very well. What is the alternative? The use of new and delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, I suspect you're running in Debug mode and have (inadvertently) set a breakpoint at the `free(cellMatrix[i]));` line.

Following Wyzard's suggestion, you could allocate a contiguous array with

```
double cellArray[] = new double[N*M*B];
```

and index into it with

```
double& cell(int i, int j, int k) { return cellArray[i + j*N + k*N*M]; }
```

Comment: Honestly, this is usually how I solve issues with multi-dimensional arrays when possible.  This or Vector<>.